# How to move scroll bar value by percentage in Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am not sure if it is a duplicate question but I could not find any answer on StackOverflow.

**Problem Statement:** I have Third party Image Viewer and PDF viewer controls. which are embedded into C# WinForms page. I want to control scrollbars movement in percentage. For example, if I press "down" key then vertical scroll bar should move down to 20% of page height. I have tried with below logic:

```
_imageViewer.VerticalScrollBar.Value += _imageHeight X ZoomFactor X .20
OR
_imageViewer.VerticalScrollBar.Value += pdfViewer1.VerticalScroll.Maximum X .20
```

Both approaches are not giving me the exact result. I think I should also consider thumb size of scroll bar but I don't know how can I get that value.

Please suggest me any good approach to moving scrollbar in the percentage of image height or width.

Comment: Scrollbars have a big hairy usability problem.  Caused by the thumb have a non-zero size.  If it is scrolled all the way up then you'd consider the top of the thumb to indicate the position.  If scroll all the way down then the bottom of the thumb is relevant.  So exactly when does it switch from top to bottom?  No standard answer.  Best thing to do is to consider the range of the scrollbar minus the thumb size to determine the position, so you never get to 100%.  The size of the thumb should be equivalent to the page size.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign [`SmallChange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollbar.smallchange(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ScrollBar` to suitable value. As mentioned in documentations, *When the user presses one of the arrow keys or clicks one of the scroll bar buttons, the `Value` property changes according to the value set in the `SmallChange` property.*

**Example:**

```
vScrollBar1.SmallChange = ((vScrollBar1.Maximum - vScrollBar1.Minimum) * 20 / 100);
```

Comment: Set `Minimum = 0` and `Maximum = imageHeight` and then by setting `SmallChange` like what I did, you can scroll it `20%` each time you click on up/down arrow.

Comment: It is not working for me. Image's height = 615, Zoom= 1.32, VerticalScrollbar.Maximum value sets automatically and I found that it is 1087. It is not setting to (image height X Zoom). Can you please share your code that how it is working, specially when image is zoomed in or out.

Comment: It worked with following logic: VerticalScroll.SmallChange = VerticalScroll.Maximum - VerticalScroll.LargeChange) * 20/100

Comment: I can not see any relation between `LargeChange` and your requirement (or maybe I couldn't understand the question correctly). The logic which I used is assigning `ImageHeight*20/100`. Now you can apply also `Zoom` factor to the formula:  `ImageHeight*Zoom*20/100`.

Comment: I guess I couldn't understand the question correctly. Do scrollbars belong to the 3rd party control? Does the control sets autoscroll itself? Do the scrollbars are standard scrollbars which you drop on form near the 3rd party control? Can you elaborate more about the question?